# replacing original file type association registry keys after uninstall of visual studio setup file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, registry, setup-project

Would like to grab the original actions associated with a file extension (in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) when an application is installed and then restore them if the application is ever uninstalled.

Already tried using batch files to simply export and restore the keys but visual studio won't accept .bat files a custom action...

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [Win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) or .NET Installer Class to backup and restore the entries. These custom actions can also use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) to launch BAT files.